# How to suggest an alternate time/date?

Tags: expressions, time

How to suggest a different time?
E.g. Manager asked (in email): "Hi, Can we go through these at 10AM tomorrow?"

Can I answer: "Can we move it an hour to 11AM?"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. In order for us to be able to answer, you should indicate *why* you think it might be appropriate or inappropriate, as this site is oriented to the mechanics of language as opposed to advice on writing style or etiquette. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That response is perfectly acceptable. Perhaps apologize and explain why you're unavailable.

For example:
"Sorry, I will be unavailable at that time. Could we move it an hour forward to 11 AM?"

Comment: I would understand "Could we move the meeting forward," to mean reschedule for 9.00 a.m.  If you wanted it at 11.00, ask for it to be postponed one hour, or delayed an hour, or re-arranged (re-scheduled) for eleven. Are these variant usages?

Comment: If nothing has been agreed before hand, why should I apologize in this case? Also, I think re-arrange or re-schedule doesn't fit as nothing has been scheduled before.